# ErrorException: Use of undefined constant exercise_c (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in fil

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
 ExerciseGroup::where('id',$exerciseGroup[0]->id)->update(['exercise_count'=>exercise_count+1]);
```

i want increment my exercise_count column value by 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
ExerciseGroup::where('id',$exerciseGroup[0]->id)->increment('exercise_count');
```